# Time complexity and loops

Tags: loops, time-complexity

Can someone explain the difference of time complexity between these two loops.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   for(int j=0; j < n; j++)
   {
        Matrix[i][j] = 0;
   }
}
```

And--->

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while(i < n)
{
    Matrix[i][j] = 0;

    j++;

    if(j == n)
    {

       j=0;
       i++;

    }

}
```

I know time complexity of the first one is O(n2).I need to know what's the time complexity of second one and if second one has a lowest time complexity,why do programmers tend to use the first one?

Comment: Same time complexity. However, the second one is less readable/maintainable than an usual nested loop. Complexity can be easily calculated by adding a `int counter` variable, incremented for each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both solutions have the same time complexity of O(n^2)

IMO the first solution is preferred as more readable